# How to convert offset string to timedelta in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion, offset, timedelta

When you call `pandas.DataFrame.resample` the first parameter `rule` is an *offset string*, e.g. '30S' (30 seconds) or '3T' (3 minutes). How do you convert such an offset string to e.g. a `datetime.timedelta` object, or just to a number of seconds?

In other words, what Python parser can translate for example '30s' to 30 and '3T' to 180, etc.?

Comment: I think the question is unclear. Do you want to translate (map) `'30S'` to a timedelta of 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes exactly. There must be a Python parser that knows how to translate for example '30s' to 30 or '3T' to 180, etc.